# Atualizar informações de p:painelGrid em tempo real

Tags: java, jsf

Preciso fazer uma tela com informações em tempo real e que vão rodar em uma TV durante 24 horas, setes dias por semana. Estudei algumas formas de fazer, utilziando RESTful e componentes do Primefaces, tal como o `<p:panelGrid>` atualizado com o `<p:poll>`. Não se está é a melhor opção de tecnologia para utilizar, podem me explicar algo sobre?

Abaixo esta um exemplo do que penso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da uma estudada em websockets, e um conselho, primefaces de longe não é a melhor opção para se trabalhar com isso.

Comment: Diego, obrigado, vou estudar sobre! Você conhece algum framework ou algo que eu possa usar como melhor opção que o primefaces?